# MySQL Trigger Syntax Error union two/three tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I wrote following code:

```
create trigger money after update on `things`
for each row
begin
   Select @c1=sum(`thing_cost`) from `things`
   UNION
   Select @c2=sum(`salary`) from `dude_base`
   Update `current` set `curr_cash`=@c1*@c2/100
end;
$$
```

Table "things" has got:

```
id1 (PK)
name
thing_cost
```

Table dude_base has got:

```
id2 (PK)
salary
name, etc. irrevelant
```

Table current has got:

```
id1 (FK)
id2(FK)
curr_cash
```

I got following error:

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to   
 your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
 near 'Update `current` set `curr_cash`=@c1*@c2/100; END' at line 7
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have a semicolon `;` like

```
Select @c2=sum(`salary`) from `dude_base`;
```

to end this query because `UPDATE` is another query

**// edit**

try it like this

```
SET @c1 = (SELECT sum(`thing_cost`) from `things`);
SET @c2 = (SELECT sum(`salary`) from `dude_base`);
UPDATE `current` SET `curr_cash` = @c1 * @c2 / 100
```

Comment: This helped, but got another problem now: `#1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger`

Comment: I'm glad it worked :) but you should set my post as answer if it works :)

Comment: you can click on "tick" icon on the left of my answer - ✓ like this :)